# WordPress get_row Function

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I found this function in a plugin I'm trying:
$result = $wpdb->get_row("DESC $wpdb->comments comment_subscribe", ARRAY_A);

I thought the first argument in the get_row('SQL', ARRAY_A) was suppose to be a SQL query.  Is the above "DESC $wpdb->comments comment_subscribe" a shorthand way to do a query in WordPress or something?

That query is suppose to return an array of comments based on the Subscribe to Comments plugin I think.

Comment: Doesn't make sense: The first argument needs to be a full query. Are you 100% sure there is nothing set additionally before the call?

Comment: I agree it doesn't make sense.  It's causing the problem too, but it does work on some sites but not on others.  So, that's why I'm trying to see how it works. I checked and all it does is create a table before this code.

Comment: Can you show the 10 lines before and after that line?

Comment: So, I figured out my problem was something different, but I'd still like to know how the above works.  Here's the result that it produces:array(6) {
  ["Field"]=>
  string(17) "comment_subscribe"
  ["Type"]=>
  string(13) "enum('Y','N')"
  ["Null"]=>
  string(2) "NO"
  ["Key"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Default"]=>
  string(1) "N"
  ["Extra"]=>
  string(0) ""
}

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK (and tested), `DESC $wpdb->comments comment_subscribe` is a complete SQL statement that will return the structure/description of that column.

`get_row` just simply executes the query and returns the first row.

However, my `wp_comments` table does not even have the column `comments_subscribe` - it's a fresh install at 3.0.1. I believe it must have been there in a past version. Maybe that's the reason for your troubles on some sites?